# java io exception: handle invalid

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to get values from a serial port and put that value to a specific row in an excel sheet according to their ID no. the first part of the code is to get check if the ID no i entered is same as the ID no in the excel sheet. then if its correct i store some data i wan to save in that specific cell.the following code is in a button so that when i press the button after each run i can enter the data to excel. my problem is when i do it once it works but if i try to do it again(twice or more times) java io exception: handle invalid is occurring. the error is pointed at the line where i create the workbook.
the only two variables that are used from a different frame is NewJFrame.fili & idd and display.maxweight. they are the file path, ID no selected and the variable i want to save respectively.

```
FileInputStream exinput = new FileInputStream(NewJFrame.fili);// getting the   input stream of excel file


    XSSFWorkbook wbb = new XSSFWorkbook(exinput); 
    XSSFSheet wsresult= wbb.getSheet("Results");
    // opening results sheet
    int newrownum=wsresult.getLastRowNum();
    for(int h=13;h<newrownum;h++){
        Cell cl =wsresult.getRow(h).getCell(0);


        if((int) cl.getNumericCellValue()==idd) {
            cl=wsresult.getRow(h).getCell(4);
            cl.setCellValue(display.maxweight);



        }

    }
    exinput.close();
    FileOutputStream setmaxvalue = new FileOutputStream(NewJFrame.fili);
    wbb.write(setmaxvalue);
    setmaxvalue.close();
    wbb.close();



}  catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Team_select.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,      null, ex);
}
```

this is the code for display jframe

```
 Thread ruu = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


                    //the timeout read blocking rates must be grater the than the arduino delay rate


                    serialPort.openPort();
                    Scanner data = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
                    serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
                    serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING,500,500);
                  int value = 0;

                 int[] weightrec;
                 weightrec =new int[20];
                 int counter=1;
                  //int newmax=0;
                    while(data.hasNextLine())
                    {
                    try{value = Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine());}catch(Exception e){} 

                           if(counter>20){
                           counter=1;                              
                           }


                           //currentmax=newmax;

                        System.out.println(value);

                        weightdisp.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                        // collects data for 10 seconds and take the max value of that 
                        weightrec[counter-1]=value;
                         for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                             if (weightrec[i-1] > currentmax) {
                            currentmax = weightrec[i-1];
                                    }
                                }


                        counter++;
                    }   


//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});




private void endButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // sets the max weight from the last recided current max
    maxweight = currentmax;
    serialPort.closePort();
    ruu.stop();




this.setVisible(false);
```

and this is the error i get.

```
Feb 22, 2016 9:55:05 AM Team_select storeButtonActionPerformed
    SEVERE: null
  java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:168)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully(ZipInputStream.java:403)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:278)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipSecureFile.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:91)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:273)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
    at Team_select.storeButtonActionPerformed(Team_select.java:235)
    at Team_select.access$200(Team_select.java:25)
    at Team_select$3.actionPerformed(Team_select.java:162)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: If that error is thrown in `XSSFWorkbook wbb = new XSSFWorkbook(exinput);` then the `exinput` is not a `InputStream` ready for reading from. Seems as if the creation the `FileInputStream` is outside the method which handles the button's action. But this is only a suspicion since you are not showing all relevant code.

Comment: what i don't understand is it works the first time i click the button. sometimes it even works for second time but suddenly it gives the java IO exception error. this is all that is inside the button. the only two variables that are used from a different frame is NewJFrame.fili & idd and display.maxweight. they are the file path, ID no selected and the variable i  want to save.

Comment: So the `FileInputStream exinput = new FileInputStream(NewJFrame.fili);` is inside the method which handles the button's action? If so please show what kind of object `NewJFrame.fili` is and where it comes from. Please do this by editing your question and **not** within a comment.

Comment: yes FileInputStream exinput = new FileInputStream(NewJFrame.fili); is inside the method.

Comment: Looks like a race condition if it sometimes works for a second time. To verify that add "synchronized" to the method that contains you first block of code. If that works you should find out where the race condition occurs.